# Rails/Angular: No route matches [GET]

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I have been following the Railscast raffler tutorial and am trying to create a new view in my users controller which will use Angular to display a list of all users with the role of "user" from the user table (I haven't implemented this yet), and then randomly select one of them to become winner (a winner field will be boolean checked to true). At the moment, I have decided to add a new method in the users controller, "raffle", and of course a corresponding view to show this. However, when I open users/raffle, I get the following error, and I seem to have followed the proper way of defining a route before resources:

```
No route matches [GET] "/raffle"
```

(Perhaps there are more optimal ways to do this, but my request is that I please use angular to achieve this because I really need to learn it.)

Here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :scholarships
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  get 'users/raffle' => 'users#raffle'
  resources :users

  get 'static_pages/instructions'

  get 'static_pages/about'

  get 'static_pages/contact'

  get 'static_pages/landing_page'

  root 'static_pages#landing_page'

end
```

Here is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  #Users who are not signed in cannot view users list
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  load_and_authorize_resource
  respond_to :html, :json, only: [:raffle]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def raffle
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    #Never trust paramaters from the scary internet, man.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
    end
end
```

My javascript file with angular:

```
var rafflerApp = angular.module('rafflerApp', ["ngResource"]);

rafflerApp.controller('rafflerController', function($scope, $resource) {
        User = $resource("/users/:id", {id: "@id"},{update: {method: "PUT"}})
        $scope.users = User.query()

        //Draw a New Winner
        $scope.drawWinner = function(){
            pool=[];
            angular.forEach($scope.users,function(user){
                if(!user.winner){
                    pool.push(user) ;
                }
            });
            if(pool.length >0) {
                user = pool[Math.floor(Math.random()*pool.length)];
                user.winner = true;
                user.$update();
                $scope.lastWinner = user;
            }
        }

});
```

My raffle.html.erb file:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.role == "Admin" %>

    <h1 class="center">Winner Raffler</h1>
    <h4 class="center">To select a winner for this year's scholarship, simply click "choose winner" below</h4>

    <div ng-controller="rafflerController"> 
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in users">
                {{user.first_name}}
                <span ng-show="user.winner">Winner</span>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
<button ng-click="drawWinner()">Draw Winner</button>
<% end %>
```

Users schema:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.integer  "role",                   default: 1
    t.boolean  "winner",                 default: false
    t.integer  "scholarship_id"
  end
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your routes.rb as follow:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # ...

  # get 'users/raffle' => 'users#raffle'  <-- remove this line
  resources :users do
    get :raffle, on: :collection
  end

  #...

end
```